# How to select first radio as default with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like this.

My main goal is when I click a radio button I show a content.
However, 
I would like the first radio to be selected as default and the div content is shown.

However, now in order to show the first content I have to click the radio button.

How can I achieve that?

BTW I am not dependent on Jquery. the whole think can be even written with native Javascript.

```js
$(':radio').change(function (event) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#' + id).addClass('none').siblings().removeClass('none');
});
```

```css
.none {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="bank" />
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="school" />
<hr />
<div id="bank" class="none">Bank</div>
<div id="school" class="none">School</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to set the `checked` attribute in the HTML then trigger the `change` event on that element when the page loads, like this:

```js
$(':radio').change(function(e) {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $('#' + id).addClass('none').siblings().removeClass('none');
}).filter(':checked').trigger('change');
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="bank" checked="true" />
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="school" />
<hr />
<div id="bank" class="none">Bank</div>
<div id="school" class="none">School</div>
```

Alternatively, if you didn't want to amend the HTML you can set the first radio to be checked programmatically, like this:

```js
$(':radio').change(function(e) {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $('#' + id).removeClass('none').siblings('div').addClass('none');
}).first().prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="bank" />
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="school" />
<hr />
<div id="bank" class="none">Bank</div>
<div id="school" class="none">School</div>
```

Comment: The content is reverse now. Under bank radio, it shows school.

Comment: That's not reversed - it's identical to the example snippet in your question.

Comment: So my example is wrong :) If you can help me to solve it as well it would be great. So when I click bank it will show bank, when I click school it will show school thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer for you. You need to swap the `addClass()` and `removeClass()` around and put a selector in `siblings()`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `checked` to `true` and then trigger the `change` event like

```
$("input[data-id='bank']").prop("checked", true).trigger("change")
```

Here is snippet

```js
$(':radio').change(function (event) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#' + id).addClass('none').siblings().removeClass('none');
});

$("input[data-id='bank']").prop("checked", true).trigger("change")
```

```css
.none {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable'  data-id="bank" />
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="school" />
<hr />
<div id="bank" class="none">Bank</div>
<div id="school" class="none">School</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
// Get all radios, then simply emulate a click on the first one
var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
radios[0].click();
```